# Will the IDE disk controller's register confuse when read and write share one register?

Tags: assembly, io, x86, disk

The IDE PATA interface: the 0x1F7 register is used as status regs when read and command regs when write.

But if I first write a command(i.e 0x20 ) to tell device that I want to write something to it,  then the next instruction I read the reg to find the status. Will it be possible that the bits on that reg is still 0x20 rather than the status bits I want?

Answer (score 3):

Although the port address is the same, there are two registers internally, a command register and a status register. An output instruction writes to the command register, and an input instruction reads from the status register.

Comment: It really helps me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

An I/O port is *not* like a normal memory location.  Read and write are separate transactions; one can't start until the previous one finishes.  (This is part of why programmed-IO is so slow).  Also, as @rcgldr explains, in this case it's two registers that just happen to share the same port number, but since one is read-only and the other is write-only they're disambiguated by the "direction".

In fact each read is guaranteed to be separately visible: e.g. repeated reads from the same IO port could give you data from a hardware buffer.  (And this is in fact how PIO instead of DMA works for reading the data response to a read request.)  So each read from the same register can have a side-effect, and HW must be designed to respect that.

This separate-transaction stuff also applies even to an MMIO register in uncacheable memory (physical address space), not just IO address space (accessible with `in` / `out` instructions) - mapping it as uncacheable makes sure that the CPU won't internally do store->load forwarding.  But that definitely can't ever happen for `in`/`out` instructions.  (MMIO, unlike in/out, does allow some pipelining, but each CPU write and read is guaranteed to be separately visible to the hardware.)

Comment: you said that " one can't start until the previous one finishes", so in the case where I write some command to the status port, then the next instruction is that I read from the port, is it true that I will get the status of the command which I previous wrote or the status that some other command leave behind.